# ajax chained call complete

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have three functions. I want to do something when function two (after one) and three are all done. What should I do?

```
function one(){
    $.ajax({
      url:'url'
    }).done(function(res){
      two();
    })
}


function two(){
    $.ajax({
      url:'url'
    })
}

function three(){
    $.ajax({
      url:'url'
    })
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you are targeting modern browsers that have support for `Promise`s, then you can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dK9tc/ that shows how you can chain with promises. You can use $.when('foo') to deliver a fulfilled promise instead of $.ajax(...);

Comment: @VictorStoddard what is the point of using `$.when(String)`

Comment: @charlietfl https://www.quora.com/What-does-foo-mean-in-computer-science

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the `$.ajax` promises from each function then you can use [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

```
function one() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'url'
  }).then(two);      
}

function two() {
  // return request promise
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'url'
  })
}

function three() {
  // return request promise
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'url'
  })
}

$.when(one(),three()).then(function(){
   //all three requests completed here
})
```

Comment: thank you ! I did this before,but I use the function two wrong. one() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'url'
  }).done(function(data){two()});      
}